# How to select multiple values and attributes ie block and lots

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute

Is there a way to select multiple polygons that have a value for the Block attribute and a value for the lot attribute. An example is BLOCK = '100' AND LOT = '1' plus BLOCK = '103' AND LOT = '9' plus BLOCK = '200' AND LOT = '12', etc, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you'd want something along the lines of:

```
(BLOCK = 100 and LOT = 1) OR (BLOCK = 103 AND LOT = 9) OR (BLOCK = 200 AND LOT = 12)
```

Of course, if those really are string fields, then you would want to put the right side of each equation in single quotes.